# First call to C function slower than subsequent calls

Tags: c, function, gcc, optimization, loop-unrolling

I am trying to approximate the function call overhead in C. So I have an empty function with the **attribute**((optimize("O0"))), so that it is not optimized away by GCC.

```
int __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) func(int a)
{
    return (a+a);
}
```

I am using the method described in the paper http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/training/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.html
to determine the time, so its pretty accurate.

So I call the function in a loop multiple times and measure the time to execute:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    t1 = start_timer();
    x = func(i);
    t2 = end_timer();

    time = t2 - t1;
}
```

I notice that the first time the function is called (i=0), it takes more cycles (~10x) than the subsequent calls. Why does this happen?

Comment: Caching. The first time you call the function, its instructions won't be in cache.

Comment: If you're compiling with -fpic or -fPIC and the function symbol has default visibility, there will also be a first time call overhead associated with symbol lookup within the dso.

Comment: Ulrich Drepper treats both of the issues in excruciating detail in https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf and in http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf.

Comment: Can be anything, from late linking to DRAM overheated, thus stalling for a short time (yes, modern systems might do that), retransmission on the bridges, buffering, cache, the weather, cosmic rays, comic rays, ray ban, etc.

Comment: Why don't you move the `t1` and `t2` timer marks outside the loop, then divide the time by 10?